# Change Notification Interrupts PIC32

Tags: pic, interrupts

I am attempting to code a program for a PIC32 where pressing the S1 button lights up the LED, and releasing it turns it off, LED2 is also blinking - using interrupts.

The pressing and releasing works, but after pressing the button, LED2 stops blinking and stays on its state. Below is a snippet of my pseudocode. Where did I go wrong?

```
void __ISR (_CHANGE_NOTICE_B_VECTOR, IPL4SOFT) CNB_Intrr (void) {
  LATA = ~PORTB;
}

int main(void) {
  TRISA = 0; // LED1  
  LATA = 0;                 
  TRISB = 1; // S1
  PORTB = 1;
  TRISC = 0; // LED2
    
  INTCONbits.MVEC = 1; // MVM mode

  asm volatile ("di");               
    
  CNCONBbits.ON = 1;   
  CNIE1B = 1; 
    
  IPCxbits.CNBIP = 4;                 
  IPCxbits.CNBIS = 0;
  IFSxbits.CNBIF = 0;                
  IECxbits.CNBIE = 1;                
       
  asm volatile ("ei");                
    
  while(1) {
    // LED2 blinking
    LATC ^= 1;
    delay_s(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with PIC32 but I imagine you need to clear the interrupt flag in your ISR, otherwise your ISR gets re-triggered forever and keeps everything else from running.

Comment: I tried adding this line of code to my ISR: IFSxbits.CNBIF = 0; and although the LED2 kept blinking, pressing S1 would just toggle ON the led. It won't turn off again after releasing nor pressing again.

Comment: @17thirty You should really accept this answer a correct, then ask another for your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change x to a number and the code as follows:

```
CNCONBbits.ON = 1;  // CNCONbits.ON = 1 
IPCxbits.CNBIP = 4; // IPC6bits.CNIP = 4                 
IPCxbits.CNBIS = 0; // IPC6bits.CNIS = 0
IFSxbits.CNBIF = 0; // IFS1bits.CNIF = 0               
IECxbits.CNBIE = 1; // IEC1bits.CNIE = 1
```